# How can i import my flask app into my app.wsgi file?

Tags: python, apache, flask

I'm trying to deploy my flask application to my Apache2 webserver. According to all the articles ive read i need to use `sys` to add my application to the path using

`sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/flask/pyapp")`

and then do

`from pyapp import app as application`

Unfortunately in my error log i keep getting the following error

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 2442944] [client 192.168.2.45:12854] mod_wsgi (pid=2442944): Failed to exec Python script file '/media/home/FS2/WEB/ChatDefender/app.wsgi'., referer: https://chatdefender.blutopia.ca/
[wsgi:error] [pid 2442944] [client 192.168.2.45:12854] mod_wsgi (pid=2442944): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/media/home/FS2/WEB/ChatDefender/app.wsgi'., referer: https://chatdefender.blutopia.ca/
[wsgi:error] [pid 2442944] [client 192.168.2.45:12854] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: https://chatdefender.blutopia.ca/
[wsgi:error] [pid 2442944] [client 192.168.2.45:12854]   File "/media/home/FS2/WEB/ChatDefender/app.wsgi", line 5, in <module>, referer: https://chatdefender.blutopia.ca/
[wsgi:error] [pid 2442944] [client 192.168.2.45:12854]     from pyapp import app, referer: https://chatdefender.blutopia.ca/
[wsgi:error] [pid 2442944] [client 192.168.2.45:12854] ImportError: No module named pyapp, referer: https://chatdefender.blutopia.ca/
```

So my question is what is the correct way to import my flask application into my app.wsgi?

Comment: Does `/path/to/flask/pyapp` contain an `__init__.py` file? I would reconsider using apache+mod_wsgi for a new service. it's not a common configuration these days, with uWSGI and gunicorn being popular choices.

Comment: Yeah it does have an __init__.py, ill look into that uwsgi thing though.